# 111: Connection refused php-fpm container docker with reverse proxy nginx error 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I think I have a link problem I have an error in my application I have a 502 bad gateway error,
and in the app log

[error] 6 # 6: * 1 connect () failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.5, server: laravel-api.art, request: "GET / HTTP / 1.1", upstream: "fastcgi: //172.18.0.19: 9000", host: "laravel-api.art" 172.18.0.5

here is my nginx config file

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  laravel-api.art;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass laravel-api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

my Dockerfile

````
  ```  FROM php:7.4-fpm

COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql  zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy application folder
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing permissions from folder to docker
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# change current user to www
USER www

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]


# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
#COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]```
````

and my docker compose
I use an external reverse proxy

````
```
    version: "3.7"
services:
  #PHP Service
  laravel-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: ${containerNameServer}
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker-files/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${VIRTUAL_HOST_SERVER},${VIRTUAL_HOST_WWW_SERVER}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${LETSENCRYPT_HOST_SERVER}
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}

volumes:
  laravel-api:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: webproxy
```
````

for information it works with other nodejs / vuejs application but this is my first laravel php-fpm application

Comment: Since nodejs and vuejs works problem is somewhere in how you run laravel php-fpm.
did you try to run it as standalone image and do `curl` request from your host?
because at the moment nginx just unable to connect to your app. I would recommend asking how to work with `laravel php-fpm container` instead of your question if your laravel image doesn't work in separate container.

Comment: @user2932688 my application works locally with docker but not on my production server with the reverse proxy

Comment: both nginx and laravel app on single server?

Comment: @user2932688 yes a server with a reverse proxy docker and the other applications in separate containers

Comment: you should try go to server and try curl request to ward laravel from server host, then from inside of nginx container

Comment: Just a side note: instead of `apt-get install` and `docker-php-ext-install` what about using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer ?